# Split de cadena con Regex manteniendo el delimitador

Tags: c#, regex, split

Tengo una cadena que me llega en JSON con unos datos como estos

> {"name":"AMD","history":{"2019-09-05":{"open":"31.79","close":"31.50","high":"32.05","low":"31.12","volume":"57693493"},"2019-09-04":{"open":"31.32","close":"30.95","high":"31.83","low":"30.85","volume":"46709780"},"2019-09-03":{"open":"30.83","close":"30.90","high":"31.14","low":"30.68","volume":"38080254"}, ... etc

usando

```
 string[] cotizacion = Regex.Split(cadena_url, @"\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}");
```

Me genera correctamente un elemento en el array cotizacion por cada dia, el problema es que el split elimina la fecha y a mi me interesa que se mantenga la fecha y la añada al array.

No consigo añadir la fecha al array.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo el problema, esa expresión regular captura cada aparición de la fecha correctamente.

Comment: hola @PaperBirdMaster Si, la captura, pero no captura la fecha en concreto que ha cumplido con la expresion, y necesito saber la fecha tambien

Comment: Pero ese split te deja como primer elemento todo el `{"name":"AMD","history":{"` anterior, luego también te deja el `":` de después... No es más fácil parsear el JSON y trabajar con el objeto? Quizás esta pregunta te pueda servir de ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list

Comment: @U.Busto perdón, me expresé mal. Esa expresión regular encuentra las fechas en la cadena, pero para capturarlas debes transformar la expresión en una expresión de captura y recorrer cada captura.

Comment: Hola @jotaelesalinas He intentado parsearlo con Json, pero me crea una clase con cada fecha.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ok, gracias, mirare a ver como se hace eso ya que no lo he hecho nunca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa expresión regular encuentra las fechas en la cadena, pero para capturarlas debes transformar la expresión en una expresión de captura (`"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"`) fíjate en los paréntesis dentro de la expresión) y recorrer cada captura:

```
String input = @"{""name"":""AMD"",""history"":{""2019-09-05"":{""open"":""31.79"",""close"":""31.50"",""high"":""32.05"",""low"":""31.12"",""volume"":""57693493""},""2019-09-04"":{""open"":""31.32"",""close"":""30.95"",""high"":""31.83"",""low"":""30.85"",""volume"":""46709780""},""2019-09-03"":{""open"":""30.83"",""close"":""30.90"",""high"":""31.14"",""low"":""30.68"",""volume"":""38080254""}";

// Recorremos cada captura (match)
// y seleccionamos la primera captura (Captures[0])
// y lo convertimos en lista
var list = Regex.Matches(input, @"""(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"":\{""open"":""([\d.]+)"",""close"":""([\d.]+)"",""high"":""([\d.]+)"",""low"":""([\d.]+)"",""volume"":""([\d.]+)""\}")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => new Registro
                {
                    Fecha = m.Groups[1].Value,
                    Open = m.Groups[2].Value,
                    Close = m.Groups[3].Value,
                    High = m.Groups[4].Value,
                    Low = m.Groups[5].Value,
                    Volume = m.Groups[6].Value,
                })
                .ToList();

// Mostramos el contenido de la lista:
foreach (var r in list)
    Console.WriteLine(r.Fecha+r.Open+r.Close+r.High+r.Low+r.Volume);
```

Asumiendo que tienes una clase para capturar los datos:

```
class Registro
{
    public String Fecha { get; set; }
    public String Open { get; set; }
    public String Close { get; set; }
    public String High { get; set; }
    public String Low { get; set; }
    public String Volume { get; set; }
};
```

Muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 2019-09-0531.7931.5032.0531.1257693493
> 2019-09-0431.3230.9531.8330.8546709780
> 2019-09-0330.8330.9031.1430.6838080254
> ```

Comment: Gracias , efectivamente eso me devuelve las fechas, pero lo que necesitaria es que me devolviera la fecha seguido de los siguientes valores, open, close, etc. He conseguido hacerlo tal que asi   string[] corte = Regex.Split(cadena_url, @"\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}");
                    string[] res = cadena_url.Split(corte, StringSplitOptions.None); en la posicion X del array corte me guarda los valores y en la posicion X del array res me guarda la fecha que toca, pero no me gusta porque es un poco chapucero, pensaba que igual existia alguna manera mas elegante.

Comment: Lo que estás pidiendo, pese a que puede resolverse con expresiones regulares, es una tarea para un parser de JSON.

Comment: Si, eso es lo que quisiera hacer, pero me mata la Fecha ya que me lo pilla como Clase cuando deberia ser una propiedad mas.

Comment: @U.Busto veo por tus comentarios que tu pregunta es muy incompleta. Antes de (otra vez) intentar resolver tu duda, por favor especifica exactamente qué es lo que necesitas: Datos de entrada, datos de salida.

Comment: Gracias, con el codigo que me has indicado me funciona muy bien, muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!